# Ashley ECS IteratingSystem not processing entity family

Tags: java, libgdx

Somehow I cannot get the `IteratingSystem` to work. In the update I double check if there are entities, it returns more then 0. But that should mean that `processEntity` gets called on those but it never runs.

```
//...
import net.madmenyo.teststuff.AshleyTest.components.MovementComponent;
import net.madmenyo.teststuff.AshleyTest.components.PositionComponent;
//...

public class MovementSystem extends IteratingSystem {
    private ComponentMapper<PositionComponent> pm;
    private ComponentMapper<MovementComponent> mm;

    public MovementSystem () {
        super(Family.all(PositionComponent.class, MovementComponent.class).get());
        pm = ComponentMapper.getFor(PositionComponent.class);
        mm = ComponentMapper.getFor(MovementComponent.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void processEntity (Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
        System.out.println("Process moveSystem");
        PositionComponent position = pm.get(entity);
        MovementComponent movement = mm.get(entity);

        position.x += movement.velocityX * deltaTime;
        position.y += movement.velocityY * deltaTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        Engine engine = getEngine();

        int count = engine.getEntitiesFor(Family.all(PositionComponent.class, MovementComponent.class).get()).size();
    }
}
```

Afaik, for each count in the update method it should run `ProcessEntity` each time the engine is updated. Since update is called the engine is updated and since `count > 0` it should be processing entities, yet it is never called. By inspecting the engine during runtime it also contains multiple entities for the family I define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`processEntity(...)` is called by the parent update method which I wasn't calling. Easy fix once I looked at it again, I just leave it here in case.

```
@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    super.update(deltaTime); // <-- call parent update
}
```